# Wordpress remove <p> tag those are auto generated

Tags: wordpress

i am trying to remove `<P>` tag those wordpress are generating automatically.

I have google for that and get solution like remove filter

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

But by using this its removing all `<p>` tag those i have already used in page content.

For example :

When i am putting plain text in page content like

**This is example.**

Wordpress wrapping these plain text in `<p>` tag like  `<P>This is example.</p>`

How can i stop this adding `<p>` tag rather than removing all `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will remove extra `<p>` for a particulate page

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ps-disable-auto-formatting/

after configuring this plugin you get an option like this, showing on example site

http://www.wordpress-plugin.net/remove-automatic-p-paragraph-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Use strip_tags() function, this will help you

Answer (score 0):

One of the good plugin in wordpress is :

[Row Html](http://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/)

Features of this plugin is :

- Disable wptexturize (the function that creates smart quotes and other
  typographic characters).
- ***Disable automatic paragraph creation.***
- Disable image smilies.
- Disable convert_chars (the function that converts ampersands to HTML
  entities and "fixes" some Unicode characters).